# What is the most efficient algorithm to generate a sequence of prime numbers?

Tags: ds.algorithms, cr.crypto-security, nt.number-theory

I know about algorithms like [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) for [generating prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes).

I would like to know what is the most efficient known algorithm to generate the sequence of $k$ distinct prime numbers all of which are larger than a given number $n$?

Comment: Do you want to find a prime number or check if a given number is prime ?

Comment: Hi, I want to find a prime number

Comment: Please check these links, and see if they suite your needs: [Generating primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes), [Efficient Prime Number Generating Algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Efficient_Prime_Number_Generating_Algorithms), and [How can I generate large prime numbers for RSA](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71/how-can-i-generate-large-prime-numbers-for-rsa).

Comment: int main() { return 17; }

Comment: @JɛﬀE : $\:$ That only finds a prime number, not prime numbers. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Sure, but OP clarified: "_I want to find a prime number_"

Comment: _only after being given options_ which included that but not what the OP originally asked for. $\hspace{.33 in}$

Comment: The most recent edit still leaves the question unclear.  Do you want the sequence of all prime numbers, an infinite sequence of distinct prime numbers, a sequence containing a certain number of prime numbers, or something else entirely?  The trivial algorithm "Return the empty sequence" solves the problem as written.

Answer (score 3):

If by efficient you mean more practical space-wise for large bounds, check the [Pseudosquares Prime Sieve](http://digitalcommons.butler.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1095&context=facsch_papers).

This (given enough time) allows searching for much larger prime numbers.